# XSLT 2.0 - Using Saxon with a VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have to process XML files with WordML, because in the end I want to have a Microsoft Word document from my XML file. But because of several problems, I do consider moving to XSLT 2.0. It would help me so much.
I read into this and downloaded Saxon for .NET usage. But I don't understand how to implement Saxon with a VBA macro...

Has someone done this or does someone know how to do this?

I haven't tried anything yet because I really don't know where to start at all.

Comment: Microsoft has a lot of documentation on extending Word with .NET code or also on calling .NET code from VBA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-from-vba-in-a-visual-csharp-project?view=vs-2022. Perhaps that is a starting point.

Comment: This seems a reasonable strategy though I've never done it myself. However, using VBA macros is not the only way to do it.

Comment: On a further look, it seems the current/latest MS Office/MS Word "generation" of add ins are using "web technologies" like HTML/CSS/JavaScript: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/. In that context it might be easier to integrate SaxonJS https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml rather than Saxon .NET.